# Jenkins while trying to execute job on docker cloud node: ‘/’ is an unsafe character

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-docker

Jenkins system log:

```
Jul 14, 2023 7:56:31 AM INFO io.jenkins.docker.DockerTransientNode$2 println

Removed container 'aee593f554f96a40ac29269c6f5f80bc6368d7c6820aa899755064e485f6e41d' for node 'jenkins/agent:latest-alpine-jdk17-0000faawen3b3'.

Jul 14, 2023 7:56:38 AM SEVERE hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner update

Unexpected uncaught exception encountered while processing agent jenkins/agent:latest-alpine-jdk17 (jenkins/agent:latest-alpine-jdk17)
hudson.model.Failure: ‘/’ is an unsafe character
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.checkGoodName(Jenkins.java:4254)
    at jenkins.model.Nodes.addNode(Nodes.java:137)
    at jenkins.model.Jenkins.addNode(Jenkins.java:2230)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner.update(NodeProvisioner.java:248)
    at hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner$NodeProvisionerInvoker.doRun(NodeProvisioner.java:823)
    at hudson.triggers.SafeTimerTask.run(SafeTimerTask.java:92)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingScheduledExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Jenkins keeps creating/removing docker containers and increasing provisioning number in Cloud Statistics every X seconds, where X is the timeout option for your docker agent template in your docker cloud, while trying to execute job.

I have only one docker cloud defined with instance capacity of 3.

Job execution status will remain "Waiting for next available executor" during this time if no other nodes/clouds are defined with available executors.

Answer (score 0):

**Name** parameter of docker agent template in docker cloud contained '/' in my case and removing it from the name solved the issue and job executed successfully.